# My downloaded flutter project showing flutter SDK not found in grdle file

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, flutter

[image]

I have installed flutter's latest version on my device
I also have given path in the environment variables in windows.

I'm not able to understand the issue altogether in this case,
at the error its giving me an option to **create Create class GradleException & properties** whilst showing **cannot resolve symbol 'GradelException' & 'Properties'**

Comment: It's just a warning because you are opening gradle files in a flutter environment you can run your flutter project without any problem. If you open your project as android project by right clicking on you project folder > Flutter > open in android studio it wont show any warnings.

Comment: check the flutter and dark sdk path in android studio as well. install the flutter and dart plugins in android studio

Comment: just ignore all that, and try to run the project